# Input element not working with flex property

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, svelte

for some reason `<input type="text"/>` wont work with `flex: 1;`

using svelte btw but I dont think it matters

```html
<main>
    <section>
        <span>Name:</span>
        <input type="text" bind:value={...} />
        <span>Age:</span>
        <input type="text" bind:value={...} />
    </section>
</main>

<style>
    main {
        width: 50vw;
        padding: 1rem;
    }

    section {
        display: flex;
        gap: 1rem;
    }

    input {
        flex: 1; /* doesnt work  */
    }
</style>
```

supposed to fit in container but instead just overflows like a 2cm flood barrier in florida after a categore 5 hurricane

Comment: wrap your input inside div

Comment: It works alright (tested in Codepen), but maybe your `main` is too narrow to fit all content with only `width: 50vw`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML input elements have a default width. To override it, try the following:

```css
input {
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: 0;
    max-width: // your preferred max width
}
```

Setting `flex-grow` to 1 and `width` to 0 will cause it to fill the parent container. `max-width` will limit its size.